# Excel returning minuscule fractional values on rounded math

Tags: excel

I have experienced this issue many times with Excel, but have no idea what causes it.

Typical math pseudocode:
    If A = sum of B,C,D, and E
        then write "X"
    Else
        Write A - sum of B,C,D, and E

The point is to see rounding errors where the difference of A and the sum of the other parts is less than 1.00.

So when the formula is:
    2000.00 = 500.00 + 500.00 + 500.00 + 500.00
It returns a value like .000000000018274

All of the values in the worksheet are hardcoded, so it's definitely not a data error (We've checked many, many times). Perhaps it's some silly issue like overflow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might just be how accurate Excel can calculate.  Here's a [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel) on just that (Numeric Precision in Excel).

Comment: See [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113).

Comment: Perfect, thanks guys